# Prince2: Can the Executive have the role as Project Assurance?

Tags: prince2

Even for smaller projects, some [PRINCE2 roles should not be combined](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/24982/why-does-prince2-specify-that-the-project-manager-and-executive-roles-cannot-be). Does anyone know if this is also the case with the roles of [Executive](http://prince2.wikidot.com/executive) and [Project Assurance](http://prince2.wiki/Project_Assurance)? First of all I'm wondering how this would inlfuence the dynamic with the [Project Manager](http://prince2.wiki/Project_Manager).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Project Assurance**

Project Board's responsibility to assure itself that the project is being conducted correctly. Each member of the Project Board has a specific area of focus for Project Assurance:

- Business Assurance for the Executive.
- User Assurance for the Primary User.
- Supplier Assurance for the Primary Supplier.

**Executive**

Individual with full responsibility to ensure that the project achieves its objectives and delivers the projected benefits. This individual should ensure that the project maintains its business focus, has clear authority, and that work, including risks, is actively managed. The Executive, in addition to being responsible for the Project Board, representing the client, is also responsible for the Business Case.

**Executive vs Project Assurance**

The Executive is responsible for the Project Board, which is then responsible for Project Assurance. However, an independent Project Assurance team may also be appointed by the Project Board.

**Implications for the Project Manager**

To the PM is given the authority and responsibility to manage the project on a day-to-day basis and to deliver the required products within the constraints agreed with the Project Board.